# Google Sheets V4 Api - how to find spreadsheetID for a given filename?

Tags: google-sheets-api

In Google Sheets API v3 you can hit https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full to get all the spreadsheets and find the spreadsheetid. How can this be done in v4 of the api?

I can easily get the data/object if I know the ID.

```
  spreadsheetId="blahblahblah"
  sheet_metadata = service.spreadsheets().get(spreadsheetId=spreadsheetId).execute()
  print sheet_metadata
```

Bigger picture is to programatically store data in spreadsheet named "abc.csv" then subsequent updates I would look for the "abc.csv" spreadsheet and update it accordingly.

Comment: It requires "spreadsheetId" for using APIs at Google Sheets API v4. When you want to retrieve sheet ID from file name, you can retrieve it using Drive API v3. By the way, can I ask you about the language you use? It seemed that you use python.

Comment: Yes python .. I did see the drive api there. I will do some more digging.

Comment: If you want help, feel free to tell me.